# Почему Bootsrap container прерывается посередине?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Количество опций на экране меняется в зависимости от действий пользователя. Bootstrap container почему-то прерывается посередине, если опций слишком много. Как  исправить? Присоедяю картинку[image]

```
<div class="container">
    <?php require "../header.php"; ?>


    <h4>Question text: </h4>
    <div id="vuespace">
        <textarea class="form-control" id="qtxt" cols="80" rows="5">{{text[0].question_text}}</textarea>

        <table class="table">
            <thead class="thead-dark">
                <tr align="center">
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th>Option</th>
                    <th>Is correct</th>
                    <th>Actions</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr valign="middle" align="center"  v-for= "(x,i) in list" v-bind:index="i">
                    <td>{{i+1}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <textarea class="form-control" v-bind:idt="i" cols="80" rows="5" v-bind:class="x.classObj" onchange="changeText(this)">{{x.text}}</textarea></td>
                    <td>
                        <input class="form-check-input check-title" type="checkbox" v-bind:checked="x.is_correct==1" onclick="makeChanged(this)">
                    </td>
                    <hr>
                    <td >
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="editOption(this)">Tools</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="deleteOption(this)">Delete</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>


        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="addNewOption()">Add Option</button>
        <br><br>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="saveChanges()">Save</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="saveAsNewVer()">Save As New Version</button>
        <div align="right">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="returnPrevious()">Return to previous version</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="nextVer()">Go to next version</button>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div align="center">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-link"  onclick="returnBack()">Return to Theme</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Нельзя дать ответ на Ваш вопрос, лишь взглянув на снимок экрана. [Приложите код](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Добавлен код...

Comment: возможно проблемы в CSS, очень сложно сказать точное решение проблемы нужно сидеть и отлавливать через инспектор